# Sitecore custom rule based configuration patching not working with word beta

Tags: patch-configuration

I faced a weird issue while doing a custom rule-based patching in the Sitecore. I defined a setting like the following:

```
<add key="beta:define" value="enabled" />
```

and then create a patch as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:beta="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/beta/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery" beta:require="!disabled">
```

but this did not work.

The strange thing is that when I replaced the word beta with any other word it worked fine, e.g., when I used the following:

```
<add key="prd2:define" value="enabled" />
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:prd2="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/prd2/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery" prd2:require="!disabled">
```

then it works fine.

Any idea?

FYI: I am using Sitecore 10.3.2 with sxa.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a typo in your configuration (or, unlikely, something SXA related).

I've tested `beta:define` and `prd:define` on Sitecore without SXA and it works as expected:

- First in `web.config`

```xml
<add key="beta:define" value="enabled" />
<add key="prd:define" value="enabled" />
```

- And then in a patch file:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:beta="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/beta/" xmlns:prd="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/prd/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
        <setting name="beta enabled" value="yes" beta:require="enabled" />
        <setting name="beta not disabled" value="yes" beta:require="!disabled" />
        <setting name="beta disabled" value="yes" beta:require="disabled" />
        <setting name="beta not enabled" value="yes" beta:require="!enabled" />

        <setting name="prd enabled" value="yes" prd:require="enabled" />
        <setting name="prd not disabled" value="yes" prd:require="!disabled" />
        <setting name="prd disabled" value="yes" prd:require="disabled" />
        <setting name="prd not enabled" value="yes" prd:require="!enabled" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Showconfig shows as expected:

```xml
<setting name="beta enabled" value="yes" />
<setting name="beta not disabled" value="yes" />
<setting name="prd enabled" value="yes" />
<setting name="prd not disabled" value="yes" />
```